# Simpy: How to implement a resource that handles multiple events at once

Tags: python-3.x, simpy

I am simulating people movements and their elevator usage. An elevator can take up multiple persons before moving to another floor. The default process has a capacity parameter, however, these indicate the number of processes and not the number of people using the elevator at the same time.

I have tried to use multiple of the resources available, such as `Container`, `Store`, and `Base`. The elevator should be requested and these objects do not have the functionality to be requested. Hence, the only suitable solution is to inherent from the `base.Resource` class. I have tried to create a subclass Elevator, implementing from base.Resource and adjusting the function `_do_get` to take multiple elements from the queue. I am pretty confident that this is not the proper way to implement it and it gives an error as well: `RuntimeError: <Request() object at 0x1ffb4474be0> has already been triggered`. I have no clue which files to adjust to make Simpy happy. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
@dataclass
class Elevator(simpy.Resource):

    current_floor: int = 0
    available_floors: List[int] = field(default_factory=lambda: [0, 1])
    capacity: int = 3
    # load_carriers: List[LoadCarrier] = field(default_factory=list)
    move_time: int = 5

    def __init__(self, env: Environment, capacity: int = 1, elevator_capacity: int = 1):
        self.elevator_capacity = elevator_capacity
        if capacity <= 0:
            raise ValueError('"capacity" must be > 0.')

        super().__init__(env, capacity)

        self.users: List[Request] = []
        """List of :class:`Request` events for the processes that are currently
        using the resource."""
        self.queue = self.put_queue
        """Queue of pending :class:`Request` events. Alias of
        :attr:`~simpy.resources.base.BaseResource.put_queue`.
        """

    @property
    def count(self) -> int:
        """Number of users currently using the resource."""
        return len(self.users)

    if TYPE_CHECKING:

        def request(self) -> Request:
            """Request a usage slot."""
            return Request(self)

        def release(self, request: Request) -> Release:
            """Release a usage slot."""
            return Release(self, request)

    else:
        request = BoundClass(Request)
        release = BoundClass(Release)

    def _do_put(self, event: Request) -> None:
        if len(self.users) < self.capacity:
            self.users.append(event)
            event.usage_since = self._env.now
            event.succeed()

    def _do_get(self, event: Release) -> None:
        for i in range(min(self.elevator_capacity, len(self.users))):
            try:
                event = self.users.pop(0)
                event.succeed()
                # self.users.remove(event.request)  # type: ignore
            except ValueError:
                pass
        # event.succeed()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is the solution I came up with.  The tricky bit is I chained two events together.  When you queue up for the elevator you get a event that fires when the elevator arrives.  This event also returns a second event that fires when you get to your destination floor.  This second event is a common event shared by all the passengers that are on the elevator and going to the same floor.  Firing this one event notifies a bunch of passengers.  This subscribe broadcast pattern can greatly reduce the number of events the model needs to process which in turn improves performance.  I use the chained events because if you are in a queue, and the guy in front of you gets on and you do not, then that guy is also going to get off before you, requiring a different destination arrive event. Put another way, I do not know when you will get off until you get on, so I need to defer that part till you actually get onto the elevator.

```
"""
Simple elevator demo using events to implements a subscribe, broadcast pattern to let passengers know when 
they have reached there floor.  All the passengers getting off on the same floor are waiting on the 
same one event.

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random


class Passenger():
    """
        simple class with unique id per passenger
    """

    next_id = 1

    @classmethod
    def get_next_id(cls):
        id = cls.next_id
        cls.next_id += 1

        return id

    def __init__(self):

        self.id = self.get_next_id()

class Elevator():
    """"
        Elevator that move people from floor to floor
        Has a max compatity
        Uses a event to notifiy passengers when they can get on the elevator
        and when they arrive at their destination floor
    """

    class Move_Goal():
        """
            wrapps passengers so we can track where they are going to
        """

        def __init__(self, passenger, start_floor, dest_floor, onboard_event):
            
            self.passenger = passenger
            self.start_floor = start_floor
            self.dest_floor = dest_floor
            self.onboard_event = onboard_event
            self.arrive_event = None



    def __init__(self,env, passenger_cap, floors):

        self.env = env
        self.passenger_cap = passenger_cap
        self.floors = floors 
        self.on_floor = 0
        self.move_inc = 1

        # list of passengers on elevator, one per floor
        self.on_board = {f:[] for f in range(1,floors + 1)}

        # queue for passengers waitting to get on elevator, one queue per floor
        self.boarding_queues = {f:[] for f in range(1,floors + 1)}

        # events to notify passengers when they have arrived at their floor, one per floor
        self.arrive_events = {f: simpy.Event(env) for f in range(1, floors + 1)}

        # start elevator
        env.process(self._move_next_floor())

    def _move_next_floor(self):
        """
            Moves the elevator up and down
            Elevator stops at every floor
        """

        while True:

            # move time to next floor
            yield self.env.timeout(5)

            # update floor elevator is at
            self.on_floor = self.on_floor + self.move_inc

            # check if elevator needs to change direction
            if self.on_floor == self.floors:
                self.move_inc = -1
            elif self.on_floor == 1:
                self.move_inc = 1

            # unload and notify passengers that want to get of at this floor
            arrive_event = self.arrive_events[self.on_floor]
            self.arrive_events[self.on_floor] = simpy.Event(self.env)
            arrive_event.succeed()

            self.on_board[self.on_floor] = []

            # load new passengers
            # get open capacity
            used_cap = 0
            for p in self.on_board.values():
                used_cap += len(p)

            open_cap = self.passenger_cap - used_cap

            # get boarding passengers
            boarding = self.boarding_queues[self.on_floor][:open_cap]
            self.boarding_queues[self.on_floor] = self.boarding_queues[self.on_floor][open_cap:]

            # sort bording into dest floors
            for p in boarding:
                # give passenger common event for arriving at destination floor
                p.arrive_event = self.arrive_events[p.dest_floor]

                # notify passeger that they are onboard the elevator
                p.onboard_event.succeed()
                self.on_board[p.dest_floor].append(p)

    def move_to(self, passenger, from_floor, to_floor):
        """
            Return a event that fires when the passenger gets on the elevator
            The event returns another event that fires when the passager
            arrives at their destination floor
            
            (uses the env.process() to convert a process to a event)

        """

        return self.env.process(self._move_to(passenger, from_floor, to_floor))

    def _move_to(self, passenger, from_floor, to_floor):

        """
            Puts the passenger into a queue for the elevator 
        """

        # creat event to notify passenger when they can get onto the elemator
        onboard_event = simpy.Event(self.env)

        # save move data in a wrapper and put passenger into queue
        move_goal = self.Move_Goal(passenger, from_floor, to_floor, onboard_event)
        self.boarding_queues[from_floor].append(move_goal)

        # wait for elevator to arrive, and have space for passenger
        yield onboard_event

        # get destination arrival event 
        dest_event = self.arrive_events[to_floor]
        move_goal.arrive_event = dest_event

        return dest_event

def use_elevator(env, elevator, passenger, start_floor, end_floor):
    """
        process for using a elevator to move from one floor to another
    """

    print(f'{env.now:.2f} passenger {passenger.id} has queued on floor {start_floor}')
    arrive_event = yield elevator.move_to(passenger, start_floor, end_floor)

    print(f'{env.now:.2f} passenger {passenger.id} has boarded on floor {start_floor}')

    yield arrive_event

    print(f'{env.now:.2f} passenger {passenger.id} has arrived on floor {end_floor}')


def gen_passengers(env, elevator):
    """
        creates passengers to use a elevatore
    """

    floor_set = {f for f in range(1, elevator.floors + 1)}
    
    while True:

        # time between arrivals
        yield env.timeout(random.uniform(0,5))

        # get passenger and where they want to go
        passenger = Passenger()

        start_floor, end_floor = random.sample(floor_set, 2)

        # use the elevator to get there
        env.process(use_elevator(env, elevator, passenger, start_floor, end_floor))

# boot up
env = simpy.Environment()

elevator = Elevator(env, 20, 3)

env.process(gen_passengers(env, elevator))

env.run(100)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the implementation! I have studied the code and I do understand it's structure! I made some adjustments to allow smart navigation and to run multiple elevators at the same time.

Comment: glad I could help.  can you tag my answer as corrent?  Thanks

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to mark your answer as correct. I am currently answering questions about pandas to increase my reputation to be able to upvote your answer.

Comment: I thought if you are the author of the question you could mark the answer as correct?

Comment: You are correct! I have accepted the answer. I also have enough reputation to upvote your answer, which I have done as well!